# Redirect multiple subdomains to different specific index.php files

Tags: javascript, php, apache, redirect

i'm hosting different sites using the same domain.
I would like to redirect each subdomain to different "index.php"
Here is an example from what i want to do:

```
subdomain1.mydomain.com --> http://subdomain1.mydomain.com/subdomain1/index.php
subdomain2.mydomain.com --> http://subdomain2.mydomain.com/subdomain1/index.php
```

This is my file structure:

```
/var/www/
    '-- html
        |-- site1
            '-- index.php
        '-- site2
            '-- index.php
```

I've been trying to achiev this by using the ".htaccess" file, but i'm not getting there.

I know .htaccess isn't the only workaround. I may use javascrip or PHP script

Comment: Then create a virtual host for each subdomain, thats how it is done

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks! Took me a while to figure it out, but worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code:

site1-->index.php code:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://subdomain2.mydomain.com/subdomain1/index.php');
?>
```

site2-->index.php code:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://subdomain1.mydomain.com/subdomain1/index.php');
?>
```